# How to provide OpenGL support to ubuntu based docker container in ubuntu based virtualbox vm

Tags: docker, ubuntu, opengl, virtual-machine

We are developing an application inside a Linux docker container using openGL. The docker container is located on a Linux Ubuntu VM running on Windows (a little bit complex but that's the way it is).

When running the openGL test application glxgears inside docker we get the following error message:

```
Command in container: glxgears
ERROR:
libGL error: unable to load driver: vmwgfx_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: vmwgfx
```

We already made openGL running on Linux but not inside the docker container (glxgears runs without any errors).

Our system setup:

- Virtualbox 6.0.3
- Graphic-Controller: VMSVGA
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Docker 18.09.3
- Docker Image: Ubuntu 18.04
- openGL 2.x

How can we provide vmwgfx_dri.so to docker?

Comment: Do you have activated OpenGL in VirtualBox? Which version of OpenGL you ask for? Is the driver for that version installed in the VM?

Comment: It seemed the driver was not not installed properly under Ubuntu, either. Installing the NVIDIA driver helped to improve the performance on Ubuntu. Your question "is the driver installed ..." triggerd this approach. Now the next step is to install this driver inside docker ...

Comment: I solved this by adding `ENV LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` in my Dockerfile.  I'm running a CentOS container with a PyQt app (to mimic the production RHEL environment).  I also run an Ubuntu VM on my Windows laptop where I create docker containers and do my development. I didn't have to change anything on my host or guest OS.